# Fortigate and FortiExplorer

Tags: firewall

i have installed FortiExplorer V1.5 and when my computer was connected with the Firewall Fortigate (by the RJ45)it doesn't launch so what's the solution !

I have tried to download FortiExplorer V2.5 if one have the setup pls !

Answer (score 0):

FortiExplorer connects to firewall with USB that is provided with the firewall. What model you are using? Some of Fortigate models do not support USB management. Then you would have to use RJ45 console (com port) or connect your computer directly to firewall ports with network cable (in default configuration it will have DHCP and web management enabled)